# Qt как определить новый COM-port во время работы автоматически

Tags: c++, qt, com-порт, serialport

Есть задачка написать программу на Qt, которая автоматически подключается к свежеподключенному COM Порту. Хотел это сделать с помощью слота. Но ни в классе `Qtserialport`, ни в `Qserialportinfo` нет сигнала показывающего наличие нового COM порта. Есть ли идеи, как это реализовать? Или какой мне сигнал использовать для решения задачи?

Comment: Наивный вариант - раз в некоторое время проверять наличие новых подключений и если что-то новое появилось, действовать по обстоятельствам

Comment: Да, как вариант можно проверять по таймеру. Но это костыль, хотелось бы знать есть ли для этого какое то решение самой библиотеки Qt

Comment: @Lancelot проверять по таймеру это не костыль - это хорошее кроссплатформенное решение доступное каждому и сделать это совсем не сложно - минут 30 максимум